# Can I use UUID as my image file name for uniquness?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am naming the image file in my rails app with UUID, e.g.`67bc91b6-fdb3-11e0-bbff-f04da2baa2d4.png`
However, I was not able to display this image correctly in my page, any clue on why this happens?

Comment: Seems like you did something wrong! Captain to the rescue. But seriously, you've asked 77 questions here and still didn't get that you need to explain in details your case to get real help. You need to solve the issue, not we, so it's in your interests to be comprehensive.

Comment: We need more details. I dont think its a problem of the filename! Where do you store the image and how did you try to include it in your application?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a demonstration of the problem?

Comment: guys, you are right. I am sorry, but for this one, I really know that much. @phihag's answer is exactly the solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of a file does not matter, and an UUID (or a hash of the content) is certainly a good way to generate a unique filename. Make sure you're sending the appropriate headers. For example, if you access your URL with `curl -I`, you should see the correct content-type:

```
$ curl -I http://localhost/APP/image/67bc91b6-fdb3-11e0-bbff-f04da2baa2d4.png
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=4
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 198542
```

If the content-type is not set or set to the wrong format, or Content-Length is not equal to the filesize, make it so.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this in other languages (C#) and had no issues; there is nothing on the web that restricts use of a UUID as an image file name. Something else must be afoot here.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like shorter filenames, that is always a good thing, you can use Base36 encoding.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36

Since it is case insensitive, it works well for all operative systems, and file names would be a lot shorter than simple UUID to Hex.